# Can you reference schema files from another VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, jsonschema

In Extension A, I have a VSCode schema file like this

```
{
    "$id": "foo.bar",
    "definitions": {
        "example": {...}
    }
}
```

In Extension B, I want to reference to foo.bar file like this

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "filters": {
            "$ref": "foo.bar#/definitions/example"
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible, without referencing the file over http?

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to reference a local file as a URI is `file:///absolute/path/name`. I don't know if VSCode will support that or not.